# Confusion in combinatorics

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, combinations

**Question (1)**

The number of different ways in which $10$ telegrams can be distributed to 2 message boys is ____?

The answer as per the book is $2^{10}$. 
But, I think answer should be $10^{2}$. 
If my answer is wrong, please let me know, how the question should to get the answer as $10^2$(without changing the numbers present in the question).

**Edit**:
The number of r -permutations of a set with n elements when repetition is allowed is given by $n^r$.
In Question-1, the number of elements(telegrams) are $10$ and the $r=2$.
Therefore, am getting the answer as $10^2$.

**Question (2)**
In the Question(1), if the telegrams are not distinguishable, in how many many many ways can we distribute the telegrams can be distributed with in the boys?

Comment: The number of different ways in which 2 telegrams can be distributed to 10 message boys is ____?

Comment: $10=10+0=9+1=\cdots=0+10$

Comment: You ask us "If my answer is wrong" to justify your wrong answer.

Comment: I just updated the question. Please check the "edit" part.

Comment: @Henry Thanks for answering the 2nd question :)

Comment: I believe you mean: If my answer is wrong, please let me know, how the question should be rephrased get the answer as 10^2(without changing the numbers present in the question).

Comment: @judithKhan Yes. That is what I meant.

Comment: @tone:  to get multidigit superscripts, put them in braces.  So to get $2^{10}$ you put 2^{10} between dollar signs.  Otherwise you get $2^10$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first telegram can be given to either of two boys.  For each of those, the second can be given to either of two boys.  For each of those... We get ten factors of two, giving $2^{10}$

For the second, now all you care about is how many each boy got.  What are the possibilities?

Comment: I just updated the question. Please check the "edit" part.

Comment: In your edit, you are computing the number of ways you can give two telegrams to one boy with replacement.  You select the first one in $10$ ways and the second one in $10$ ways.  That is not the question that is asked.

Comment: Got it. Thanks for helping. :)

Comment: I am reading your edit.  Repetitions are not allowed in the problem because they both can't deliver the same telegram. Additionally you are not distributing all of the telegrams.

Comment: @judithKhan:  I agree.  I was reacting to OP's edit, where he gets $10^2$ and showing what I thought the logic was to get that answer instead of the correct one.

Comment: @judithKhan: As you said that, all the telegrams are not distributed if we go with the answer 10^{2}. Can I say that the number of telegrams left are are 8?
(Because, I got 10^{2} as answer(wrong answer) only after distributing 1 telegram to each of the mail man.)

Answer (score 0):

to answer your editing question:  The number of different ways in which 2 telegrams can be distributed  by 10 messengers is 10^2.